# E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate

Tags: installation, pip, package, setup.py

Upon installing a software, I am finding the following error multiple times.

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from software_name import PACKAGE_NAME
  File "/home/username/Softwares/software_name/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import scipy
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

I can install many of the missing modules with, e.g., `sudo apt-get install -y python-numpy`, but sometimes I get:

```
username@username:~/Softwares/software_name$ sudo apt-get install -y python-scipy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-scipy is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate
```

And I am really not sure what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The package you want is `python3-scipy`, not `python-scipy`. It can be installed using:

```
apt install python3-scipy
```

You might be better off installing `scipy` via pip (for Python 2) or pip3 (for Python 3). pip is a package manager for Python packages.

```
pip install scipy
```

or

```
pip3 install scipy
```

If you run into a similar problem in the future, you can use pip3 search `scipy` with the relevant search term to look for the required package. Check out man `pip3` for the details.

Comment: let me know if that works for you, i can update it